# Use object of controller in another controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two controller Controller A and controller B . controller A has an object $scope.operation={}; which is a json containing details.

In controller B I want to  compare the detail of this json object and then run a function in COntroller B .How to achieve this..Thanks

Comment: you can use $rootScope or Factory to communicate between controller

Comment: Is B's view nested in A's view? Where does the data come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a factory/service to store the `operations` array, whenever the value changes in the `ControllerA` controller update the values in service.

```
myApp.factory('myService', [function() {
        var operations = {};
        return {
            getOperations: function() {
                return operations
            },

            setOperations: function(op) {
                operations = op;
            },
        }
    }])
    .controller('ControllerA', [function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.operations = {};
        $scope.$watch(function() {
            return $scope.operations;
        }, function() {
            myService.setOperations($scope.operations);
        });
    }])
    .controller('ControllerB', [function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.operations = myService.getOperations();
    }]);
```