# Update $scope value from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a side menu and its controller. In another controller I get the user data and want to update my menu items. How to achieve that  ? I tried using $watch and services but to no success. Also I never used $rootScope so please avoid if it is not the only solution.

```
.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.username = ""
})
.controller('afterloginCtrl', function($scope) {
var a = "this is username"      
$scope.username = a // here I wish to update username in menuCtrl
    })
```

Please let me if you need more code or details.

**EDIT**

Actually I update user info via database table, from their I am retrieving the username and other info. So menu controller needs to update with current values in database every time

Comment: Use a service to share data

Comment: I tried using service but still data is not updated

Comment: Why don't you use `$rootScope`? Using `$on` and `$broadcast` with `$rootScope` is one of the best way to achieve your issue.

Comment: Where is the service code? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095714/use-object-of-controller-in-another-controller-in-angularjs

Comment: I was using factory let me see if service works

Comment: @IzumiSy using `$rootScope` and `$broadcast` is one of the *worst* ways to achieve this. Services exist to share state. Using `$rootScope` is usually a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Your edit is completely different question.

Comment: sorry for the alteration i was expecting answers using $watch but services are not the thing that i wanted to use

Comment: @sam did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can to use some service for sharing data between controllers.
For example:

```
.service('currentUser', () => ({data: {}, someMethod: () => {}}))
.controller('Ctrl1', (currentUser, $scope) => {$scope.user = currentUser.data;})
.controller('Ctrl2', (currentUser) => {currentUser.data.name = 'username';});
```

Obviously, you can also extend your service with some appropriate methods. etc.

Then you can use these methods:

```
.controller('Ctrl2', (currentUser, api) => {
   api.retrieveUser()
     .then(user => currentUser.setData(user));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.service('loginuser', () => ({}))

.controller('fistCtrl', (currentUser, $scope) => {
  $scope.data1 = loginuser;
})

.controller('secondectrl', (loginuser) => {
  loginuser.name = 'sessionname';
})
```

Comment: excellent rewrite work.. You forgot to rename first controller injected `currentUser`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15066041)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using service or factory data will be lost after page refresh.
You Can use browser session storage.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('NAME', "XYZ"); //set Data
sessionStorage.getItem('NAME'); // Get Data

//Afetr use you can clear data.
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Need always to use some angular wrapper about global objects. Using them directly makes code untestable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage`

Use the following code in your **first controller**:

```
localStorage.setItem($scope.username);
```

and the **next controller**:

```
$scope.username = localStorage.getItem();
```

Comment: That's rather working around the problem. A service is for sharing state.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above comments your requirement is to persistent the username if user closes app and reopens.So, by using service or factory data will be lost once app reload or close.

**Work around :**

You can use `localStorage` to store username and can also access the data across controllers.

**Code :**

You can create a common factory service that will save and return the saved local storage data based on the key.

```
app.factory('storageService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    return {
        get: function(key) {
            return localStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        set: function(key, data) {
            localStorage.setItem(key, data);
        }
    };
}]);
```

**In controller :**

Inject the `storageService` dependency in the controller to set and get the data from the local storage.

```
.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope','storageService',function($scope,storageService) {
    // Get local storage data from storageService
  storageService.get('username');
}])
.controller('afterloginCtrl',['$scope','storageService',function($scope,storageService) {
    var a = "this is username"      
    // Set local storage data to storageService
    storageService.set('username', a);
}])
```